# Apollo boost receiving null on nested queries

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

We are working with graphQL and React Apollo 2.1 to do some queries. The query has three nested components. The query works fine in graphiql and we get results for all fields. Once we put it into the app and make the call we get all the fields except the nested fields come back as null.  Below DeviceList calls the query connector witch calls the query. Any ideas?

```
export const mapDeviceQuery = gql 
  query mapDeviceQuery($input: String, $type: DeviceSearchEnum) {
    devices(input: $input, type: $type) {
      id
      client
      productKey
      alias
      imei
      subFleet
      warranty
      isActive
      locate{
        latitude
        longitude
        speed
        heading
        date
        time
      }
      address{
        full
        street_address
        city
        state
        zip
      }
    }
  }
```

deviceList.hoc.js

```
render = ({loading, error, data} = this.props) => {      
  let deviceList = [];
  if(data.devices){
    console.log(data.devices);
    for(let i=0; i<data.devices.length; i++){
      if(data.devices[i].isActive){
        let d = data.devices[i];
        deviceList.push({
          key : i,
          alias  : d.alias,
          driver : d.driver,
          subFleet : d.subFleet,
          imei : d.imei,
          address : d.address.full,
          date : d.locate.date,
          time : d.locate.time
        });
      }
    }
}
```

queryconnector.js

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Query } from "react-apollo";
    const queryConnector = (queryGQL) => WrappedComponent => {
      class QueryConnector extends Component {
        render = () => {
          return (
            <Query query={queryGQL}>
              {({ loading, error, data }) => {
                console.log(loading)
                console.log(data)
                return (
                  <WrappedComponent
                    runQuery={queryGQL} loading={loading} error={error} data={data}
                    {...this.props}
                  />
                )
              }}
            </Query>
          )
        }
      }
      return QueryConnector
    }
    export default queryConnector
```

Comment: Are you populating the `input` and `type` variables when running your query in GraphiQL?

Comment: yes. I get all every from the top "id" down starting with id and ending with "isActive".  locate and address come back as null. in graphiql they come back with the correct data.

Comment: Your `Query` component does not set any variables for the query that's passed to it, which could explain you seeing different results on the client vs GraphiQL